# How to catch a HTTP 404 in Java

Tags: java, jsp

I have a web application and I have a problem 
If the web page does not exist in my application I have got the following error page

```
HTTP Status 404 - /myapplication/department/home.html

type Status report

message /myapplication/department/home.html

description The requested resource (/myapplication/department/home.html) is not available.
```

I want to forward user to the index page, if this problem happen , without he knows How to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify the index page as 404 default error page in `web.xml`.

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I assume that you are aware that this is bad for user experience and SEO? If it is for example a page which you have (re)moved, then you should rather create a filter which does a 301 redirect to the desired location.

Comment: thanks alot what about if index.jsp is located in one folder up home.html page. I tried to write <location> ../index.jsp </location> but it does not work . Can you please tell me how to go one step back in the URL

Comment: The given example should already do that. The leading slash `/` makes it relative to the webapp's context root. It'll display `/myapplication/index.jsp`.

Comment: well, I tried that it dispalyed /myapplication/department/index.jsp.

Comment: That can only mean that you used `<location>index.jsp</location>` instead of `<location>/index.jsp</location>`. Or there must be some filter in the chain which disturbs the request/response, or there is some bug in the container used.